# Mysterious line added to web.config on solution load

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-framework-version

In a .NET/C# 4.6.1 targeted console application using topshelf to host/install a windows service asp.net solution I get a line auto-added to the web.config when opening & building the solution in Visual Studio 2017 15.9.9 and can't find any reference to it anywhere on the internet. Anyone know what this line does?

```
<add key="UseNoOpProvider" value="true"/>
```

Comment: This may be related to the `Azure providers`, please see this link: (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AspnetTeam.AspnetProvidersConnectedService)

Comment: What is a "Windows Service ASP.NET solution"? Is it a self hosted Web API? And why does it have a web.config if it's a Windows Service?

Comment: Windows-service hosted asp.net web api solution. Because it's still a web solution, it's just hosted by a windows service.